# Find size of page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, size

How do I find the size of a page using Javascript?

for example: http://google.com = 5mb (which, of course isn't true)

I can only find pointers on finding how *long* it takes for a page to load, which has some relevance to the size, but I would like to find out the size of the page, if possible!

(Also, how do I check if the result I get is true? Is there already a website to do this? (I realise this part of the question *may* be off topic for this site. If it is, then please ignore it!))

Comment: Why do you want to do this in Javascript? You can download webpages using curl or any other HTTP lib of your choice and Javascript has access to the parsed Document tree, not to the raw HTML.

Comment: @hugomg I just want to find the size of the page without downloading anything - is this possible? There isn't really any reason. What I'm trying to do is, whenever I want to find the size of a page, I quickly type some Javascript in the Console (in Google Chrome).

Comment: in that case, the Network tab is probably going to give you the most accurate information (just make sure you have it open before you open your target page). I dont think its possible to always find the page size before you download it - when you deal with dynamic pages there might be situations where the server itself doesnt know the size before it sends the page back...

Comment: @hugomg Well, is there no possibility to extract the size from the Network tab? Is there an API to receive text from the Netowork tab in Chrome?

Comment: I'm not sure but considering how often the dev tools change that API would probably not be very stable if it exists. If you want to automate things I would suggest using a proxy to intercept your browser's requests.